# AWS cli/boto3- Is it possible to know if a role or policy has permissions over a resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I would like to know if I can check if a policy or role can see, list, or edit a resource.

Can be any type of resource, S3 bucket, Secrets Manager, EC2 instance, etc.

I will try to do this through boto3 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [Test IAM policies with the IAM policy simulator - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html). This allows you to specify a policy and a resource (including conditions) and test whether the API call would be permitted.

If you wish to do this via boto3, you can use  [`simulate_custom_policy()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.simulate_custom_policy):

> Simulate how a set of IAM policies and optionally a resource-based policy works with a list of API operations and AWS resources to determine the policies' effective permissions. The policies are provided as strings.
>
> The simulation does not perform the API operations; it only checks the authorization to determine if the simulated policies allow or deny the operations.
>
> If you want to simulate existing policies that are attached to an IAM user, group, or role, use [`simulate_principal_policy()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.simulate_principal_policy) instead.

Comment: Nice. Is it a new addition to boto3?

Comment: Nope. Looks like it has been around for years: [AWS re:Invent 2016: How to Automate Policy Validation (SEC311)](https://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/aws-reinvent-2016-how-to-automate-policy-validation-sec311)

Comment: Awesome! We have tested simulate_custom_policy in aws cli to check user permission, but we couldn't check a role or policy directly.
We'll try again!